# web scraping a table from interactive websites using rvest

Tags: python, r, web, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape the table on this interactive web page
https://games.crossfit.com/leaderboard/open/2019?country_champions=0&division=1&citizenship=US&citizenship_display=United+States&sort=0&scaled=0&page=1

Below is my original code:

```
url='https://games.crossfit.com/leaderboard/open/2019?country_champions=0&division=1&citizenship=US&citizenship_display=United+States&sort=0&scaled=0&page=1'
US_male=read_html(url)%>%
  html_nodes('#leaderboard')%>%
  html_nodes('div.lb-main.container')%>%
  html_nodes('div table')
```

after doing this, it returns {xml_nodeset (0)}, but if I shorten it to

```
US_male=read_html(url)%>%
  html_nodes('#leaderboard')%>%
  html_nodes('div.lb-main.container')
```

it returns

```
{xml_nodeset (1)}
[1] <div class="lb-main container"></div>
```

if you inspect the web page, there is the tag for table body`<tbody>` under `<table class="desktop athletes">`. I'm not able to understand why the content of the table not showing up and how should I correctly scrape the table?

Whether you use R or python, I can learn both if it would work. I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Easier way:

Use Rselenium(R) or Selenium(Python). Those two packages both make use of Selenium where you can simulate a browser which executes all the javascript and AJAX requests.

Then you can download the parsed page source and use `rvest` or `BeautifulSoup` to parse the HTML.

### Harder way

Use developer tools in your browser and check the XHR content in Network Tab.

For example, the table you want is actually sent to your browser in JSON format.

https://games.crossfit.com/competitions/api/v1/competitions/open/2019/leaderboards?country_champions=0&division=1&citizenship=US&citizenship_display=United+States&sort=0&scaled=0&page=1

You can compare the URL query parameters and make your own requests using the API directly.

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
url <- "https://games.crossfit.com/competitions/api/v1/competitions/open/2019/leaderboards?country_champions=0&division=1&citizenship=US&citizenship_display=United+States&sort=0&scaled=0&page=1"
response <- httr::GET(url,user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36"))
data <- content(response,type = "application/json",as = "parsed")
```

The remaining work is just to convert the list into a data frame.